"Trouble concatenating char values alongside int and float in C"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b, c = 14, d; 
    float e = 7.586, f, g = 682.546, h;
    char i = 'b', j, k = 'h';

    b = a + c;
    f = e + g;
    j = i + k; 
    printf("the value of a and c of addition is  :%d\n",b);
    printf("the value of e and g of addition is  :%f\n",f);
    printf("the value of a and c of addition is  :%c",j);
}

i am trying to concatenate the int,float,character value but i got only the concatenate value of int and float value character cannot...is anyone explain how to solve this problem???

You'll have to tell what the expected output is. You talk about concatenation but the code says addition, those are two different things.

Adding 2 chars does not concatenate them as if they were strings, but does an arithmetic addition of their undelying values (in ascii here).

Plus sign + does addition not concatenation. 10+14 = 24.

I removed the basic tag since it's for question involving the basic language.

On common systems using ASCII derivative encodings, 'b' is the value 0x62 or 98, 'h' is the value 0x68 or 104. When adding them you first obtain 202 or 0xca which is mapped to a non ASCII character but the actual character depends on the encoding. On the common Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) you would get 'Ê'.

printf("%c%c", i, k)

When you add characters, you are actually adding ASCII codes in the background. For example, when you add these two characters ! (ASCII value 33) and " (ASCII value 34), the result is 67, which is C if you look at its equivalent in the ASCII table.
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b, c = 14, d; 
    float e = 7.586, f, g = 682.546, h;
    char i = '!', j, k = '"';

    b = a + c;
    f = e + g;
    j = i + k; 
    printf("the value of a and c of addition is  :%d\n",b);
    printf("the value of e and g of addition is  :%f\n",f);
    printf("the value of a and c of addition is  :%c\n",j);
}

OUTPUT:
the value of a and c of addition is  :24
the value of e and g of addition is  :690.132019
the value of a and c of addition is  :C

If I need to explain in more detail what the system actually does when two char types are added: char data type: 8-bit, i.e. 1 byte. A variable of char type actually contains the numerical equivalent (ASCII code) of an ASCII character. For example, the ASCII code of the character 'a' is 97. When you add, you add the ASCII equivalents, which creates unexpected characters.
ASCII equivalents in the example you gave
char i = 'b'; // ASCII 98
char k = 'h'; // ASCII 104
char j = i + k; // j = 98 + 104 = 202

You can see the ASCII equivalent on this page.
The value corresponding to 202 may not be supported by the terminal you are outputting from, so you may see it as "�". You can understand these signs as invalid characters.
